# Microsoft SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql. I would like to ask what should I do when I will create a database using a stored procedure. 
I usually do this to create database: `create databse db_mydatabase`
a database name db_mydatabse will be created. 
Question: how will I  able to create a database using stored procedure?

Comment: which dbms you used

Comment: Why do you want to create a database from a stored procedure?

Comment: thanks for your comment honeybadger. i am just wondering if it is possible to create a database using stored procedure. I am using SQL 2017 for what i understand is that i have to type this code create database db_mydatabase and it will create a db_mydatabase for me. The scenario is what if i want to automate the creation of database using stored procedure that if i want to create a new database i would just execute the Stored procedure and provide the database name and a new database is created.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
create procedure sp_create_db @name nvarchar(500)
as 
begin 
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql='CREATE DATABASE '+@name;
EXECUTE(@sql)
end
```

Comment: ehsan kiani thanks for the help i was able to do it. Just one question is it a default behavior that when a stored procedure created not inside the regular database it will go to the master database under programmability stored procedure? that's what i observe i am new to database. thanks a lot.

Comment: Every user in SQL server have a default database when,you can change the database you want to work at the moment but if you don't change it it should be the master.If you want more information I suggest you ask another question, and please mark this answer as correct if it's useful,thanks.

Comment: thanks you very much ehsan kiani for your explanation.